# Jetty client: send request with a large payload

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to send POST request with a large payload using Jetty client 9.3.3
But seems like my jetty client is not sending the whole payload.

Is there a payload size limitation by default?
How can I make it able to send a large payload?

[EDIT] here is my code (in short):

```
httpClient = new HttpClient(new SslContextFactory(true));
httpClient.start();

request = httpClient.newRequest(url.trim());    
request.method("POST");
request.content(new StringContentProvider(LargePayload,"UTF-8"));

response = request.send();

stopHttpClient();
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Show your work/code, how are you using the jetty client? (as there's many possible ways to use it)

Comment: hi, I edited my question with my code structure.

Comment: That seems sane, are you getting any errors? exceptions? logging output?  or any kind of detail that can help someone answer this for you? (just saying "seem slike my jetty client is not sending the whole payload" is not sufficient)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no limitation to the request payload size.

How do you know that Jetty client is not sending the whole payload ?
Do you have exceptions ?

If you add more details, it would be possible to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the poblem is not coming from Jetty client. I am getting the payload from an xml file and the StAX parser is not given me the whole payload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631293/parsing-xml-with-stax-not-getting-a-large-content-tag