# Parsing xml with StAX: not getting a large content tag

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using StAX to parse my xml file, the problem is that when the tag content is large, StAX is not able to give me the whole content.
Here is a part of my xml doc, the content of payload tag is so much more larger, can't print it all in SOF:

```
<payload>{\"id\": \"ENTITY24\",\"attr1\": {\"type\": \"sensor\",\"type\": \"type1\",\"value\": \"val1\",\"metadata\": {}}}</payload>
```

Here is a part of my code parsing it:

```
if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("payload")){
    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
    if(xmlEvent.isCharacters()){
       setPayload(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());                           
    }
}
```

Any idea why StAX is not able to give the whole tag content?
Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either concatenate all `isCharacters` events between other events or set the [IS_COALESCING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#IS_COALESCING) property.

Just like with SAX, STAX may offer you one single run of characters as multiple events.